# Angular2: Injecting a provider into a component using a custom decorator or annotation?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, ionic2, angular2-services

I'm hiding tabs in Ionic 2 for certain `@Page`s (an Ionic 2 decorator) using a simple `TabsProvider`:

`tabs.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class TabsProvider {
  currentState = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
  public showTabs(){
    this.currentState.next(true);
  }
  public hideTabs(){
    this.currentState.next(false);
  }
}
```

The tabs component subscribes to `currentState`, and `TabsProvider` is injected into various pages as below:

`sample-page.ts`:

```
import {Page} from 'ionic-angular';
import { TabsProvider } from './tabs';

@Page({
  ...
})
export class SamplePage {
  tabsProvider: TabsProvider;

  constructor(tabsProvider: TabsProvider) {
    this.tabsProvider = tabsProvider;
  }

  onPageWillEnter(){
    this.tabsProvider.hideTabs();
  }

  onPageWillLeave(){
    this.tabsProvider.showTabs();
  }
}
```

This code is practically all boilerplate, and would be much cleaner if I could define this functionality in a decorator (or annotation), e.g.:

```
import { Page } from 'ionic-angular';
import { hideTabs } from './tabs';

@hideTabs()
@Page({
  ...
})
export class BuyPage {
}
```

But I'm having trouble determining how to inject TabsProvider and add the `onPageWillEnter` and `onPageWillLeave` methods to SamplePage.

## Can a decorator (or annotation) somehow inject additional Angular providers?

The farthest I've gotten so far:

in `tabs.ts`:

```
export function hideTabs() {
  return function(cls: any) {
    cls.prototype.onPageWillEnter = function() {
      this.tabsProvider.hideTabs();
    };
    cls.prototype.onPageWillLeave = function() {
      this.tabsProvider.showTabs();
    };
    return cls;
  }
}
```

This gets us part of what we're looking for, but it's still necessary to import and inject `TabsProvider` as a specific instance member:

`sample-page.ts`

```
import {Page, Events} from 'ionic-angular';
import { hideTabs, TabsProvider } from './tabs';

@hideTabs()
@Page({
  ...
})
export class SamplePage {
  constructor(public tabsProvider: TabsProvider) {
  }
}
```

## Is it possible to fully abstract this into `@hideTabs()`?

#### Edit:

Relevant parts of the tabs component (for anyone interested in implementing) `pages/tabs/tabs.ts`:

```
import { Page } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TabsProvider } from './tabs';

@Page({
  ...
})
export class TabsPage {

  ...

  currentState: boolean;
  constructor(TabsProvider: TabsProvider) {
    TabsProvider.currentState.subscribe((state: boolean) => {
      this.currentState = state;
    });
  }
}
```

`pages/tabs/tabs.html`:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'hide-tabs': !currentState}">
  <ion-tabs>
    ...
  </ion-tabs>
</div>
```

`pages/tabs/tabs.scss`:

```
.hide-tabs ion-tabbar-section {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just had the same problem, and this is the solution I came up with. The general approach is to:

- Use `Reflect.getOwnMetadata` to read the existing dependencies from the class.
- Add to the list of dependencies
- Create a new constructor which wraps the old constructor and deals with these dependencies.

`tabs.ts`:

```
    import TabsProvider from "./tabs";

    export function hideTabs() {
      return function(cls: Function) : any {

        // Save existing onPageWillEnter and onPageWillLeave inplementations
        let enter = cls.prototype.onPageWillEnter || function () {};
        let leave = cls.prototype.onPageWillLeave || function () {};

        // Create new constructor for class
        const newCls = function (tabsProvider, ...args) {
            this.__hideTabs__tabsProvider = tabsProvider;
            return cls.apply(this, args);
        }

        // Copy prototype to new constructor
        newCls.prototype = constructor.prototype;

        // Copy metadata to new constructor
        let metadatakeys = Reflect.getMetadataKeys(cls);
        metadatakeys.forEach(function (key) {
          Reflect.defineMetadata(key, Reflect.getOwnMetadata(key, cls), newCls)
        });

        // Read dependencies list from 'cls', add our own dependency, and write list to 'newCls'
        let dependencies = Reflect.getOwnMetadata('design:paramtypes', cls);
        dependencies = [TabsProvider].concat(dependencies)
        Reflect.defineMetadata('design:paramtypes', params, newCls);

        // Define new onPageWillEnter and onPageWillLeave implementation which implement tab show/hide functionality
        // and also call the old implementation saved above (if they exist)
        newCls.prototype.onPageWillEnter = function() {
          this.tabsProvider.hideTabs();
          enter.apply(this, arguments);
        };

        newCls.prototype.onPageWillLeave = function() {
          this.tabsProvider.showTabs();
          leave.apply(this, arguments);
        };

        return newCls;
      }
    }
```

I would also recommend moving the `@hideTabs` decorator below the `@Page` decorator

Comment: You, sir, are f**** genius! Idea is awesome, I believe that it is correct approach. Thank you!